# GetWindowText does not work

Tags: winapi, vb6

I'm trying to retrieve the text from an EDIT control using GetWindowText and GetWindowTextLength. The application retrieves the text from the window under the cursor and it works on all windows with a caption or text with the exception of the EDIT control. The EDIT control is the result window on the Windows XP Calculator, calc.exe.

```
Dim S As String
Dim L As Long

L = GetWindowTextLength(handle) + 1

Receiving string = GetWindowText(handle, S, L)
```

EDIT:

According to SPY++ the Edit class control does not receive the EM_GETSELTEXT or the WM_GETTEXT message.The code below retrieves the text from the Edit class control on the Windows XP calc.exe calculator every time that I press a button on my UI. It is not the method that I would have preferred to use, however, it accomplishes my task.

```
    Const EM_SETSEL = &HB1
    Const ES_READONLY = &H800
    Const WM_COPY = &H301
    Const EM_GETSELTEXT = &H43E
    Const WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = &HE
    Const WM_SETFOCUS As Long = &H7

    Dim L As Long

    L = SendMessage(EditHwnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0&, 0)

    SendMessage EditHwnd, WM_SETFOCUS, 0&, 0

    SendMessage EditHwnd, EM_SETSEL, 0&, L

    SendMessage EditHwnd, ES_READONLY, 0&, 0 ' read only = false

    Clipboard.Clear

    SendMessage EditHwnd, WM_COPY, 0&, 0

    SendMessage EditHwnd, ES_READONLY, 1&, 0 ' read only = true

    Receiving string = Clipboard.GetText

    Clipboard.Clear
```

Comment: MSDN: *GetWindowText cannot retrieve the text of a control in another application ... To retrieve the text of a control in another process, send a WM_GETTEXT message directly instead of calling GetWindowText.*

Comment: And of course any application designed to thwart this sort of hijacking uses windowless controls making the task much tougher.

Comment: @Bob77: You mean, like *calc.exe* in Windows 7 and above? ;) Seriously, though, use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753388.aspx). It'll get the job done even in those scenarios, where no native Windows control is available for tinkering.

Comment: Alex K, Your statement regarding GetWindowText being limited to the application that is making the call is incorrect. I have tried SendMessage handle, &HD, GetWindowTextLength(handle) + 1,  Formatted string and it also fails to retrieve the text.

Comment: Bob77, My application says that the class is Edit. According to research the text should be returned using the WM_GETTEXT, however, it fails.

Comment: IInspectable, Is it possible that the Windows 7 OS is blocking the call? It works on every other window and control regardless of the ownership. You cited Windows 7 calc.exe. I have not tried that control but the Windows XP calc.exe wants not part of my call. Both GetWindowText and WM_GETTEXT work on all of the other windows so I know that my code is correct.

Comment: I merely said, that what you think is an EDIT control simply may not be an EDIT control. Even if it looks **exactly** like an EDIT control. Qt, for example, will render all of its widgets, that all look like native Windows controls, without ever using a single native control. Browser, too, commonly use what is called *window-less controls*. You cannot hope to get this to work reliable, without a reliable solution. It's called UI Automation (and even that won't do under all circumstances).

Comment: IInspectable, Perhaps this will help you to understand that the control is definitely EDIT Class with a handle: http://i843.photobucket.com/albums/zz354/CNC4Cheap/EDIT%20Class_zpsakxbou1j.jpg

Comment: My statement is a direct copy/paste from the MSDN page for GetWindowText, they don't want you using it for perfectly good reasons: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/08/21/54675.aspx

Comment: You don't seem interested in what anyone else says. In that case Stack Overflow is not for you. You've completely ignored the advice to use automation. You ignore MSDN. Why ask if you won't listen?

Comment: David, I'm not a programmer so if there was a solution offered then I did not recognize it. SPY++ was unable to retrieve the text but, trapping the edit field messages revealed that the control was not receiving the messages for retrieving the text. I'm still open to a better solution if you would care to provide a better solution without the attitude.

Comment: @Ron: A better solution has been provided 3 days ago. 3rd comment: *"use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753388.aspx)"*.

Comment: IInspectable, Please explain the difference between UI Automation and APIs. When I Googled > UI Automation and Visual Basic 6 < then it returned three pages and none of the URLs tied UI Automation to Visual Basic 6. MSDN states that it is supported in XP SP3 and up. I'm on Windows 7 on this machine and my shop computer is running XP Pro w/SP 3 so I should be able to use UI Automation if I knew what it was.

Comment: @Ron: Hyperlinks are a wonderful invention. You have been given a link to **exhaustive** documentation, twice. Is it too much to ask, that you clicked it?

Comment: IInspectable, I literally do not have time to learn a new programming language. Case Closed

Comment: @Ron: UI Automation is exposed through COM objects. COM objects can be used from any language that supports COM. This includes VB6. Your consistent claiming, that you aren't a developer is irritating. Stackoverflow is **specifically** for developers. You need to look for support elsewhere, if you aren't a developer.

Comment: C A S E...C L O S E D !

Comment: @Ron: I'm afraid to break the news: You don't make the rules around here. A case is closed, when a question has an exhaustive answer. This is no longer your question, since you donated it into the public domain. It is the question of any developer, who has the same issue, or knows the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long

Function GetText(handle As Long) As String
    Dim S As String, L As Integer, cch As Long
    L = GetWindowTextLength(handle) + 1
    S = String(L, 0)
    GetText = Mid(S, 1, GetWindowText(handle, S, L))
End Function


Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim hw As Long
    hw = Me.hwnd
    MsgBox GetText(hw)
End Sub
```

But it will not work with controls like EDIT, as it is written in help. ;( In order to get the text of the child window (control), try to get a list of all windows using API EnumWindows/EnumThreadWindows/GetWindowThreadProcessId, to find the desired control.

---

What is the name of the class to EDIT You need? What is its width and height? I could write code specifically for the search for this control.

Comment: The North Star,

Thank you for at least making an effort to help. I failed to format the receiving string in my original post, however, it was formatted in my code.

I'm very familiar with enumerating windows and child windows. I use the child process to get the handle for the controls on the XP calc. When I push a button on my App then SendMessage CtrlHwnd, &H5, 0&, 0  pushes the corresponding Button, CheckBox and Option on the minimized XP calc.

SPY++ shows that the Edit class window doesn't receive the messages for retrieving the text so my solution appears to be the only solution.

Comment: The North Star, If SPY++ cannot retrieve the text from the Edit class control then I don't believe that Visual Basic 6 and APIs will not retrieve the text by using conventional methods. I'm anxious to learn about UI Automation and whether or not that it is compatible with VB6. I have written several DLLs and a couple of drivers in C, however, it is not my neighborhood. I wrote a new compiler for VB6 and it facilitates using a .def file for creating dynamic linked libraries so I haven't worked in C for several years.

Comment: Try Autoitx.dll (autoitscript.com).

Answer (score 0):

this code works fine in Windows XP (virtual machine)

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
(ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As Any, ByVal lpsz2 As Any) As Long

Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByRef lParam As Any) As Long

Private Declare Function AttachThreadInput Lib "user32.dll" _
(ByVal idAttach As Long, ByVal idAttachTo As Long, ByVal fAttach As Long) As Long

Private Const WM_GETTEXT As Long = &HD&
Private Const WM_GETTEXTLENGTH As Long = &HE&

Function WindowText(ByVal hWnd As Long) As String
    Dim ret As Long
    ret = SendMessage(hWnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, ByVal 0&)
    WindowText = String(ret, 0)
    ret = SendMessage(hWnd, WM_GETTEXT, ret + 1, ByVal WindowText)
End Function

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim hCalc As Long, hEdit As Long
    hCalc = FindWindow("SciCalc", vbNullString)
    hEdit = FindWindowEx(hCalc, 0&, "Edit", vbNullString)
    MsgBox WindowText(hEdit)
End Sub
```